# Bool HttpCookie redirect to a landing page not working successfully

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been working on a script to send the user to  a landing page, providing they haven't already seen it today using a HttpCookie:

```
bool userVisited = false;
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Hoarding"];
if (cookie == null)
{
   cookie = new HttpCookie("Hoarding");
   cookie.Values.Add("userVisitedSplash", "true");
   cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
   cookie.HttpOnly = true;
   this.Page.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
} 
else 
{
    if (!Boolean.TryParse(cookie.Values["userVisitedSplash"], out userVisited)) 
    {
        userVisited = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        Response.Redirect("/default-splash.aspx");
    }
}
```

This code redirects successfully, but once ENTER SITE is pressed on the landing page, it redirects again to the splash. Not taking into account it has visited it already.

Is there something obviously wrong here?

Comment: Are you seeing the cookie being set in the browser?

Comment: Problem is that the last `else` branch will be taken if there is a cookie and TryParse succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could you please try this;

```
 bool userVisited = false;
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Hoarding"];
        if (cookie == null)
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie("Hoarding");
            cookie.Values.Add("userVisitedSplash", "true");
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            this.Page.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
            Response.Redirect("/default-splash.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            if (Boolean.TryParse(cookie.Values["userVisitedSplash"], out userVisited))
            {
                if (!userVisited)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("/default-splash.aspx");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("/default-splash.aspx");
            }
        }
```

Comment: you genius! Can't thank you enough! Good day to you :-)